# Markers Drifting Position when Zooming

Tags: google-maps-api-3, position, google-maps-markers

Greetings all,

I've developed some javascript code that draws two-point Polylines (straight lines).
In zoom_changed event I calculate the position of lines mid point and I create a Marker at that position.
I noticed that as I zoom in further these Markers keep drifting from the actual mid point on the lines !

What is wrong with this technique (see code below) ?

Regards

```js
function label() {
    for(var i in links) {
        if(links[i].label != null) {
            links[i].label.setMap(null);
            delete links[i].label;
        }

        if(links[i].view == view && map.zoom >= links[i].minZoom) {
            var lat = (links[i].coords[0].lat() + links[i].coords[1].lat()) / 2.0;
            var lng = 0.0;
            var latLen = Math.max(links[i].coords[0].lat(), links[i].coords[1].lat()) - Math.min(links[i].coords[0].lat(), links[i].coords[1].lat());
            var lngLen = Math.max(links[i].coords[0].lng(), links[i].coords[1].lng()) - Math.min(links[i].coords[0].lng(), links[i].coords[1].lng());
            var slope = latLen / lngLen;

            if(lngLen < 180.0)
                lng = (links[i].coords[0].lng() + links[i].coords[1].lng()) / 2.0;
            else
                lng = (360.0 + (links[i].coords[0].lng() + links[i].coords[1].lng())) / 2.0;

            links[i].label = new google.maps.Marker({
                map: map,
                position: new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng),
                icon: "http://chart.apis.google.com/chart?chst=d_text_outline&chld=FFFF66|11|h|FF6600|b|" + links[i].text
            });
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Geeko (love that handle),

There may be nothing wrong with your code... Google maps displays a "diagram"... they don't even attempt to display a "map" in the strict sense of the word. Everything "shifts" all over the place as you zoom in or out. About 100km of the NT coast just "went missing" for a while. It's a diagram. Great for what it is (absolutely brilliant actually, IMHO)... just don't expect it to be ACCURATE.

Cheers. Keith.

Answer (score 0):

The error is where you write

```js
(links[i].coords[0].lng() + links[i].coords[1].lng()) / 2.0;
```

This does not give the mid point of the line. To find the mid point of a line, use the geometry library's [interpolate()](http://www.google.com/url?sa=D&q=http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/reference.html#spherical) function
You will also have to set the 'geodesic' option on your polyline and use this:

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false&libraries=geometry"></script>
```

Ben (from Google Maps API forum)